# Minecraft (1.13+) - Get Player By UUID using commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a commands that give an arrow to the player that fired the arrow.
The arrow object has `Owner` key that contains `UUID` of the player.

Is there a way to select a player with an `UUID` from an arrow object?

Give command:

```
/give @a[nbt={UUID:???}] arrow 1
```

Where `???` should be the value of

```
@e[type=arrow].Owner
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky thing. Simply due to the fact we cannot compare NBT tag values directly. However, if we store the first chunk UUID of a player in a scoreboard...

```
execute as @a[scores={uuid=0}] store result score @s uuid run data get entity @s UUID[0]
```

Then store the Owner UUID of the arrow...

```
execute as @e[type=arrow, tag=!returned, scores={uuid=0}] store result score @s uuid run data get entity @s Owner[0]
```

Then all you need to do is compare the scoreboard values to determine who shot the arrow and give the player the item

```
execute as @a if score @s uuid = @e[type=arrow, tag=!returned] uuid run give @s arrow
```

Finally, tag the arrow with `returned` so we don't have an infinite arrow glitch

```
execute as @e[type=arrow, tag=!returned] if score @s uuid = @a uuid run tag @s add returned
```

This works in 1.20.1 Java Edition. I didn't do any testing outside of that version because I use a modded client (for shaders, optimization, etc). The process should be functional in all versions of Minecraft with `/data`, `/execute if`, `/execute store`, and `/scoreboard`.

I should note that you cannot store the entire UUID of the player inside a scoreboard. This is because the entire UUID of the player uses 4 integers (128 bits) and scoreboard uses 1 integer (32 bits). In a nutshell, this means there is a chance a player shares this first UUID int and would randomly receive an arrow and the player who actually shot it will not. You can fix this by using more scoreboards and a larger `execute if` statement, tracking if a player shot an arrow, or just roll with it. The chance of this happening is astronomically low, but it is still possible and thankfully easy to fix.